# Manim error: It's a sound problem that I haven't seen anywhere else

Tags: ffmpeg, manim

I've been using Manim for about a month now, and with already existing impediments to my progress none has been more painful than the lack of sound when I got to [this part of Theorem of Beethoven's tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tsMGRN3ZfAg&list=PL2B6OzTsMUrwo4hA3BBfS7ZR34K361Z8F&index=20). I've been struggling with it for three weeks and opened issues on GitHub and Reddit without any success.

So the code looks like this:

```
class AudioTest(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        group_dots=VGroup(*[Dot()for _ in range(3)])
        group_dots.arrange_submobjects(RIGHT)
        for dot in group_dots:
            self.add_sound("click_this_and_nothing_else",gain=-10)
            self.add(dot)
            self.wait()
            self.wait()
```

And the error message is a bit long and I'm still cracking at what it actually means. Here it is:

```
C:\Manim\manim-18june>python manim.py tutorial\7_add_audio.py AudioTest -pm
Media will be written to C:/Users/NeoPlato/Videos/manim_videos\. You can change this behavior with the --media_dir flag.


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Manim\manim-18june\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 155, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "C:\Manim\manim-18june\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.file_writer.finish()
  File "C:\Manim\manim-18june\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer.py", line 379, in finish
    self.combine_movie_files()
  File "C:\Manim\manim-18june\manimlib\scene\scene_file_writer.py", line 506, in combine_movie_files
    self.audio_segment.export(
  File "C:\Users\allan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pydub\audio_segment.py", line 911, in export
    raise CouldntEncodeError(
pydub.exceptions.CouldntEncodeError: Encoding failed. ffmpeg/avlib returned error code: 1

Command:['ffmpeg', '-y', '-f', 'wav', '-i', 'C:\\Users\\NEOPLATO~1.000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpk6j8yj98', '-b:a', '312k', '-f', 'mp3', 'C:\\Users\\NEOPLATO~1.000\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmpyn225uxk']

Output from ffmpeg/avlib:

ffmpeg version git-2020-06-17-0b3bd00 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt
--enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 55.100 / 56. 55.100
  libavcodec     58. 92.100 / 58. 92.100
  libavformat    58. 46.101 / 58. 46.101
  libavdevice    58. 11.100 / 58. 11.100
  libavfilter     7. 86.100 /  7. 86.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
Guessed Channel Layout for Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'C:\Users\NEOPLATO~1.000\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpk6j8yj98':
  Duration: 00:00:04.23, bitrate: 2822 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s32le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s32, 2822 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s32le (native) -> mp3 (mp3_mf))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp3_mf @ 011be000] could not find any MFT for the given media type
[mp3_mf @ 011be000] could not create MFT
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!



I do have a larger documentation of the problem with current progress [over at GitHub](https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/1152)

>Help
>>Me
>>>Please :(
>>>>Pardon my naive looking formatting, I'm new to Markdown
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess, it's late, but here it is.

Update to latest version of manim community `Manim Community v0.4.0` as of this time.

simply use `self.add_sound(filename, gain)`

The latest version has implemented add_sound method.

Comment: I tried it but it says the file is unsupported

Comment: I did that and got a new laptop so it's all good now anyway

Answer (score 0):

#### Add the `-c:a libmp3lame` output option

Your `ffmpeg` version is automatically choosing the MP3 encoder named *mp3_mf*, which is the MediaFoundation MP3 encoder, but this encoder is [too picky](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65311354/).

Perhaps *mp3_mf* has improved since these questions were asked, so if you actually want to use *mp3_mf* then update your `ffmpeg` from the git master branch.