# 'unsupported input sample rate set' error while converting mkv to mp3 with ffmpeg on python

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg

I'm getting this error on trying to convert some mkv files to mp3 via python. Nearly all files got converted, but some are facing this issue. 
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/663255565451001866/788424224661569596/Error.txt

Please help me fix this issue.

ffmpeg output extracted from the discord link above:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-06-04-7f81785 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.3.1 (GCC) 20200523
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --disable-w32threads --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 49.100 / 56. 49.100
  libavcodec     58. 90.100 / 58. 90.100
  libavformat    58. 44.100 / 58. 44.100
  libavdevice    58.  9.103 / 58.  9.103
  libavfilter     7. 84.100 /  7. 84.100
  libswscale      5.  6.101 /  5.  6.101
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'J:\DC ED\Original\045 'Kimi no Egao ga Nani Yori mo Suki Datta' by 'Chicago Poodle'.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : 045 'Kimi no Egao ga Nani Yori mo Suki Datta' by 'Chicago Poodle'.mkv
    COPYRIGHT       : © 2013 APTX4869 Fansub
    creation_time   : 2020-11-18T05:03:06.000000Z
    COMPOSER        : Chicago Poodle
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.44.100
  Duration: 00:01:20.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2023 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(jpn): Video: hevc (Main), yuv420p(tv), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : VIDEO[AVC]
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.90.100 libx265
      BPS-eng         : 1831510
      DURATION-eng    : 00:01:20.039000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 1919
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 18324032
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v49.0.0 ('Sick Of Losing Soulmates') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-11-18 05:03:06
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(jpn): Audio: aac (LC), 96000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : AUDIO[AAC]
      BPS-eng         : 188626
      DURATION-eng    : 00:01:19.999000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 3750
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 1886246
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v49.0.0 ('Sick Of Losing Soulmates') 64-bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2020-11-18 05:03:06
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:0 (aac (native) -> mp3 (mp3_mf))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp3_mf @ 000002142f4a5fc0] MFT name: 'MP3 Encoder ACM Wrapper MFT'
[mp3_mf @ 000002142f4a5fc0] unsupported input sample rate set
Error initializing output stream 0:0 -- Error while opening encoder for output stream #0:0 - maybe incorrect parameters such as bit_rate, rate, width or height
Conversion failed!
```

Comment: It's always better to show your command so that we can find solution..

Answer (score 1):

You are using the encoder *mp3_mf* which is the MediaFoundation MP3 encoder. Seems like a picky, troublesome encoder. Even if you add `-ar 48000` it may still fail with the error `nb_samples (1024) != frame_size (0)`.

To fix it use a different MP3 encoder. Use the output option `-c:a libmp3lame` (instead of `-c:a mp3_mf` if you used that).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

*libmp3lame* will automatically choose the appropriate sample rate, so no need to add `-ar`.

Comment: @AgentMerlot Usually it would have "just worked" but for whatever reason mp3_mf was used (can't see your command so not sure if you picked it or not), and that encoder seems not very robust.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as the output alludes (`unsupported input sample rate set`), is that the input has a sample rate of 96kHz, but mp3 can only support sample rates up to 48kHz.

Put `-ar 44100` between the input and output files in the command line and it should work for you. If you need a specific sample rate on the output, just change 44100 for eg 48000, 32000.

See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options for more detail.

FWIW, you should really paste the full, unedited, ffmpeg command line and output in the description when asking a question like this - it's generally a prerequisite to getting any useful help.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm kinda new, so I'm not really sure how the editor works